# JSTL hasRole chained with boolean condition

Tags: spring, spring-security, boolean, jstl

So I have a conditional list that may be added to the page, And I only want to check for it if the user has an Admin Role.

I am trying to do as so:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')">
        <c:if test="${empty list}">
    </sec:authorize>

//do stuff here

<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')">
     </c:if>
    </sec:authorize>
```

It keep looking for an ending close tag, so this wont compile.

My question is, is there a way to chain a role check along with a boolean check.

Something like this:

```
<c:if test="${empty list && hasAnyRole('ADMIN')}">

//...DO STUFF HERE

</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to save the result of `<sec:authorize>` execution in a variable and use it later in the JSTL expression:

```
<sec:authorize var="isAdmin" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')">

<c:if test="${isAdmin and empty list}">
    //do stuff here
</c:if>
```

Comment: Also you can use `hasRole('ADMIN')` instead of `hasAnyRole('ADMIN')`.

Comment: Thanks  for that.